# Continuing to drink a Beverage after Birchas HaMazon?

Tags: blessing, bentching, meal-seudah

Perhaps this is a simple matter that I should be embarrassed not to know (which I am even if it isn't because I need to learn hilchos b'rachos better and always forget to look this question up) but....:

If I am drinking beverage with my meal and have decided I am finished eating but would like to continue drinking what is the proper procedure? Should I wait to bentch (say birchas hamazon) until I have finished drinking, bentch and continue drinking with a berachah achronah as necessary, bentch make another berachah (l'vatalla?) and then a berachah achronah, or otherwise?

(Of course I am not asking l'maaseh, but the answer will hopefully point me in the right direction, and remind me to study the topic from the sources and ask any relevant sheilos.)

Comment: Simple solution: [Bentch on a kos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11969/759) and then the brachot on the wine/grape juice will exempt all other beverages.

Comment: Do not be embarrassed. This is what we are here for.

Comment: ולא הביישן למד.

Comment: Just to point out, your question is compounded if you want to move places during that time when you drink (eg. coffee for the car or something), or if you plan on drinking for longer than you are allowed to bentch.

Comment: @DoubleAA The situation I'm thinking of is more continuing a conversation after eating. If I'm running my mouth I have to keep drinking... :)

Comment: What if you finished your meal but your hot beverage is too hot to drink? Can you bentch and make a new bracha?

Comment: @DoubleAA, would you care to post a source supporting the effectiveness of your recommendation?

Comment: @SethJ https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%91 https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_making_berachot_after_kiddush/

Comment: msh210 found http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21881

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef (Orahh Hayim 174:8) [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_12.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%93B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9FB%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AAB%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9FB%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9DB%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%97) (my translation):

> ואם התחיל לשתות או לאכול בתוך הסעודה, וממשיך לשתות או לאכול הדבר אחרי ברכת המזון, צריך לברך.
>
> And if one started drinking or eating during a meal and continues drinking or eating the item after Birkat HaMazon, one must make a blessing.

Comment: But is he allowed to do that or is it a problem of forcing an extra bracha to be needed?

Comment: Given the utmost importance and severity which Hakham Yitzhaq Yosef SheLIT"A and Hakham 'Ovadiah A"H assign to Berakhot LeVatalah or Berakhot She'einan Tzerekhot, and given the rest of the se'if, it may be understood that while there are better options (e.g. waiting until after the meal to make a blessing on and drink the beverage), it is not *assur* as such to begin drinking during the meal and make a bless after Birkat HaMazon to continue drinking.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. The OP asks what to do at the outset; this answer what to do if one already Bentched. Concur with @DoubleAA.

Answer (score 1):

A Berachah SheEinah Tzerichah (unnecessary blessing), although not exactly the same thing as a Berachah LeVatalah (blessing made in vain), is a very bad thing. Finish drinking first, then Betnch.

Source:
The Shulchan Aruch writes ([OC 215:4][1]):

> כל המברך ברכה שאינה צריכה הרי זה נושא שם שמים לשוא, והרי הוא כנשבע לשוא ואסור לענות אחריו אמן.‏
>   Anyone who says an unnecessary blessing has taken God's name in vain and it is forbidden to recite Amen after him.

(Much thanks to Double AA's comment below.)

Comment: Your first statement is correct it seems, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18450/759.

Comment: Equal opportunity downvoter?

Comment: @SethJ +1 - that would be the l'chatchila option. It's unclear if the questioner is asking l'chatchila or b'dieved (usually the case on Mi Yodeya).

Comment: @LN6595, since the OP asks if he should wait to Bentch, I think this solves the problem by answering that that would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you have 72 minutes to continue the meal in which you ate bread with fruit, drink etc.. Therefore you should finish drinking and then bentsch.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12316/759

Answer (score 0):

if you are still drinking then you didn't finished your meal yet. drinking is a part of the meal, if you say hamosi you don't do a beracha for the beverages during the meal. (except for wine of course)