# Bracha achrona stipulation

Tags: blessing

The question here [Continuing to drink a Beverage after Birchas HaMazon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18662/continuing-to-drink-a-beverage-after-birchas-hamazon) is a good question. Unfortunately it's been deflected with a bracha she'eino tzricha svara.

Here's a different case. Someone is eating an egg and a coffee for breakfast. The blessing of shehakol (on the egg and coffee) was made with the intention of drinking some of the coffee where he is then, and taking the rest to go, whereas his intention concerning the egg was to finish it in the original location.

When the egg is finished, he should have to make his bracha achrona on it where it was eaten, but then he runs into the issue of the leftover coffee.

Does his borei nefashos automatically end his drinking session?

Can he have explicit intention to have it not apply to the coffee?

Should he rather not make a borei nefashos at all until he finishes his coffee?

(*Since people are answering without being aware of something called Holchei Derachim, I would suggest seeing siman 178 siff 4. As the achronim point out it is completely allowed to change places when one's intention was to not be kovea makom in the first location. One continues eating on the new place, with the bracha made in the first place*)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34603/discussion-on-question-by-user6591-bracha-achrona-stipulation).

Comment: msh210 found http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21881

Answer (score 1):

I just asked a Rav I know a very similar question: what if I was eating a banana and sipping water. (While sipping water, you usually drink too slowly to complete a shiur within the time needed to get a bracha acharona.)

He told me to say a Bracha Acharona upon finishing the banana. This would cancel both the haadama and the shehakol. I would then be required to wait five minutes or so, and then say a new bracha on my drink.

I understand your coffee may get cold.... so good luck on figuring out a practical solution. Maybe buy yourself a Contigo thermos ; )

Comment: +1 You wait 5 minute to get thirsty not to say shehakol when you are not thirsty, but if it is not water you can say shehakol even when you are not thirsty, maybe ask him what will be the law with coffee, and for the reasoning to say the after brocho before finishing the water, thanks

Comment: @hazoriz The reason you wait 5 minutes is in order not to say the bracha rishona immediately after the bracha acharona. The identical halacha would apply to coffee.

Comment: thank you why not say the after brocho after finishing the water?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34563/discussion-between-ln6595-and-hazoriz).

Comment: @LN6595 I think your answer implies that water does not require a bracha achrona, which could easily mislead people. Unless you have a source that water does not generally require a bracha achrona, I hope you will edit your answer for clarity.

Comment: @SAH Done. Let me know if still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The implication in the question is that one has left the kitchen (or the place where one has been eating) after the eggs are finished. If one continued to sit at the table and drink the coffee, then it appears that the question has not come up.

I deal with this question in [Should you say a new Bracha on coffee when leaving the coffee shop?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65670/should-you-say-a-new-bracha-on-coffee-when-leaving-the-coffee-shop/65671#65671) The fact that you have left and will be eating in a different place requires you to make a bracha acharona and make a new bracha rishona in the new place. As is pointed out in the sources that I quote there, there is a difference between going from room to room (within the same house) and going outside (as you say in the question - "coffee to go").

Note that this requires a new brach whenever a shinui makom occurs no matter what the original intent was. That is, even if the original intent was to leave in the middle and finish elsewhere, once one is going to leave the house (according to the sources that I cite) one must still make a new bracha upon leaving.

[Leaving the house](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/28-Leaving-the-House.html)

Orach Chaim 178:1; Rema – Orach Chaim 178:2
Mishnah Berurah 178:39

> Walking outside of your house implies that you have stopped this
>   eating session, and is therefore considered a shinuy makom. This is
>   true whether you go out to the street, or even simply walk out to your
>   own backyard. As soon as you leave the building where you started
>   eating, you've made a shinuy makom and a new bracha is necessary if
>   you want to continue eating.
>
> This is true whether you want to continue eating outside, or even if
>   you immediately come back inside to continue eating there. The mere
>   act of leaving the house ends your original eating session, and
>   terminates the original bracha along with it.
>
> The reverse is true as well. If you began eating outside, and then
>   walk into your house (or any other building), a new bracha is
>   necessary if you want to continue eating.

Comment: I don't think this answer address the case of the person who had intention from the beginning to leave (which is what the question asked about).

Comment: This does not address a holchei derachim, someone who consciously knows at the time of the bracha he will be moving to a different location.

Comment: @Daniel The question of shinuy makom as explained in the answer that I point to includes whether or not one intended to eat in multiple places or not. The fact that one does leave is sufficient to require a new bracha because of shinui makom. I will attempt to make that clearer.

Comment: @sabbahillel Please provide a source for that because I do not believe you are correct about that.

Comment: @sabbahillel See [here](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha/1157-after_blessings__bracha_achrona___changing_locatio?fs=1&r=7&st=Bracha+achrona)

Comment: +1 You got it but I did not see your answer until I submitted mine

Comment: @Daniel You link is regards to a meal with bread but something that has an afterbrocho of bore nifashois is different

Answer (score 0):

Regarding hoilchai drochim this law only applies to bread see [taz 178.9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x995)

---

From [Siddur birchas hanenenin 9.11,12,13,14,15](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/9.htm) see footnotes below for original sources

Regarding *to go*
Things that are borai nifashois if you take them to another place, having in mind only helps (not having to say another first brocho) if the second place is in the same house, or you can see the first place,

*Does his borei nefashos automatically end his drinking session?*
**His leaving the place ends his drinking session**

*Can he have explicit intention to have it not apply to the coffee?*
**It is not good to say extra brochois** ([shulchan aruch harav 215.4](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/18/215/4.htm))

*Should he rather not make a borei nefashos at all until he finishes his coffee?*
**I guess so**

[image]
 [image]
 [image]
[image]

[image]
 [image]
 [image]
 [image]
  [image]

Comment: You were right, I read it wrong.