# Should you say a new Bracha on coffee when leaving the coffee shop?

Tags: halacha, blessing, eating

If I drink a coffee in a coffee shop, do I need to make another blessing when continuing outside if that's common for me to do?

http://berachot.org/halacha/10_location.html says:

"Additionally, you don’t need express intent – as long as you habitually would do it then it would work.For example, if you’re eating in the dining room, but you always make trips into the kitchen or to the garage to get more food or whatever – then that would be sufficient. Additionally you don’t need explicit intent to go to the bathroom during a meal."

Does the above apply to inside->outside shinui makkom?

Answer (score 6):

The following shiurim say that moving outside requires a new bracha rishona even if you come back inside to eat.

According to [New Beracha after Moving Between Rooms](http://dinonline.org/2011/11/07/new-beracha-after-moving-between-rooms/) implies that outdoors does require a new bracha

> The best method to avoid doubts is by having in mind at the time of
>   the beracha that you will be moving from room to room, and in this
>   case one does not get into doubts, and it is permitted to move from
>   room to room (**but not outdoors**) without making a new beracha

There is a series of shiurim on [Jewish Pathways](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/27-Introduction-to-Shinuy-Makom.html) that deals with this issue says that walking outside requires a new bracha as long as you are not eating with other people and they remain.

Mishnah Berurah 178:2

> In determining when a change of place effects a  shinuy makom, the
>   halacha  takes three factors into account:
>
> 1) What type of  location change  did you make: a minor change  (e.g.
>   from room to room), or a major change (completely out of the  house)?
>
> 2) What  type of food  were you eating?
>
> 3) Were you  eating alone, or with others who remained in the 
>   original location?
>
> Not every change of place signifies the end of an eating session. Only
>   a major change, i.e. one that you would not normally make in the
>   middle of eating, terminates your bracha. Let's explore the
>   parameters:

[Leaving the house](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/28-Leaving-the-House.html)

Orach Chaim 178:1; Rema – Orach Chaim 178:2
Mishnah Berurah 178:39

> Walking outside of your house implies that you have stopped this
>   eating session, and is therefore considered a shinuy makom. This is
>   true whether you go out to the street, or even simply walk out to your
>   own backyard. As soon as you leave the building where you started
>   eating, you've made a shinuy makom and a new bracha is necessary if
>   you want to continue eating.1
>
> This is true whether you want to continue eating outside, or even if
>   you immediately come back inside to continue eating there. The mere
>   act of leaving the house ends your original eating session, and
>   terminates the original bracha along with it.
>
> The reverse is true as well. If you began eating outside, and then
>   walk into your house (or any other building), a new bracha is
>   necessary if you want to continue eating.2

In the [summary](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/339776852.html)
 Rabbi Y.S. Elyashiv, cited in Halachos of Brochos, pg. 146, footnote 26.5; V’Zot HaBracha, pg. 61, citing V’Tein Bracha 146

> Mike is eating alone in a crowded school cafeteria. He leaves the 
>   building for a minute to make a phone call. That constitutes a shinuy 
>   makom – even though when he returns there are still hundreds of  other
>   people eating in the same place – since Mike was not “eating 
>   together” with those people.