# Reason behind making a new Bracha when walking into another room

Tags: halacha, blessing

I remember once hearing that if you’re eating & change rooms you have to repeat the bracha. Is my memory right? And what’s the logic behind this Halacha?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65670/should-you-say-a-new-bracha-on-coffee-when-leaving-the-coffee-shop?rq=1