# When you need to make a bore nifashois do you have to make it in the place you started to eat

Tags: halacha, blessing

When you need to make a bore nifashois do you have to make it in the place you started to eat (as @LN6595 seems to claim [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67441/5120)).

Or even if you are planning to continue in another place (and will have to make another first brocho) you should wait until you finish there and then make the bore nifashois.

Comment: @LN6595 did you see this question?

Comment: i think its based on a gemara in pesachim that you do.

Comment: @hazoriz Yes, and I agree with Cauthon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Boreh Nefashot* has easier *halachot* than *Birkat HaMazon* and *Me'eyn Shalosh*, and so even though it is preferable to say it where you ate, so as not to forget to say it if you leave, it's not mandatory.

Source - Rabbi Eliezer Melamed [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/9276), with a few sources mentioned there as well. He also mentions some who say that if it's one of the seven *minim* then it might be important enough to return to where you ate it.

Comment: +1 the link does not work for me

Comment: @hazoriz it does for me. Here's an image of the text for your convenience: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4vUrIGZBqoWmw5Ni10UnE3WHc/view?usp=sharing