# How long are brachot applicable to a given food?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, time, hefsek-interruption

If I start, say, drinking a bottled drink or eating chips from a bag, then later (in the day, in the week) continue to eat from it, do I need to make a new brocha? If so, how long can the pause be before a new brocha is needed?

Assume I am either eating in the same place, or specifically had in mind that I would be moving when I made my brocha.

Comment: 72 min, or until you are hungry again. things that do not have a special after brocho having in mind to move will not help you in not having to make another brocho.

Comment: @hazoriz Many thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by the last sentence...what is "a special after brocho having in mind to move"?

Comment: See the  images hear http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67417/5120 if it is water having in mind to change the place will not help and if you change the place you need to make a new brocho, but if it is a meal with bread then it will and you do not need to make a new brocho, wine and the special fruits the law is unclear so we should avoid the situation

Comment: @hazoriz I believe what you commented above specifically applies to a bracha achronah. The time frame limit for a bracha rishona is different.

Comment: @yydl Ah, that's important then...I'm definitely interested in limits on brachot rishona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I'm going to take a shot at answering this. I originally didn't want to as there is actually a lot to say on this topic. But on second thought, I could start with just answering the actual question, and allowing for potential follow-up if additional clarity is needed. So please comment if something isn't clear:

---

Unlike a Bracha Achrona, which has a time-limit, a Bracha Rishona actually doesn't have a time limit (according to most Poskim).

For example, you can make a Hoadama right now on a bag of chips sitting in front of you, and take as much time as you'd like to munch through the bag. Even pausing for say 1.5 hours in between munches will not clear the effective status of the Bracha Rishona.

**However**, there are certain things that do affect the Bracha Rishona:

- The additional items must be covered by the original bracha to begin with. There are many rules that govern what items a bracha includes (e.g. same bracha category, in front of you, will be served, having in mind, etc.)
- It can be terminated by a change of location
- It can be terminated by a decision to stop eating (note: the halachic definition of "decision" in this case actually requires a bit more than just a thought)
- It can be terminated by the recital of a Bracha Achrona
- It can be terminated by going to sleep (depends on the type of sleep and various halachic opinions)
- And there are even more...

Keep in mind that each and every one of these bullet points is actually a small representation of a lengthy topic.

So while the bottom line is that time alone will not affect a Bracha *Rishona*'s status (hence the answer to your question: "How long"), many other things can.

The source for most of the above is a careful reading of the seforim: Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner and The Laws of B'rachos by Rabbi Forst. You may want to read them for additional clarity (they are both written in English).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting and thorough answer. Is it correct that  any bracha achrona terminates the |term| of any bracha rishona made before?