# Do you need to make an afterbrocho before sipping a drink slowly

Tags: halacha, blessing

If after a meal you will be drinking something slowly do you need to make an afterbrocho right away (as @LN6595 seems to claim [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67441/5120)).
Or you should wait until you finish the coffee before you make the afterbrocho.

Does the answer change if eating a full meal or if eating just fruits.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21881

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until finishing drinking and then make one after-Bracha on your whole meal or snack. To do otherwise would be to cause a Bracha She'ayna Tzricha.

Comment: That comment is regarding a different scenario which has a different Halacha.

Comment: Please explain...

Comment: Btw Source regarding borcho sheaina tsricha http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/18/215/4.htm (I bring the English there in my answer)