# Does coffee need a bracha if you have it every day after a meal?

Tags: blessing, kavana-intent

If almost everyday after my lunch I have coffee. If I had something like chicken that required a shehakol does the coffee become exempt from requiring its own shehakol (assuming I did not make an after blessing and 72/30 minutes had not yet expired)?

What about if I start drinking this cup of coffee in a different room within the same house?

**Motivation for the question:**

Upon making a blessing one can have in mind to have other items included in the blessing and make only a single one to cover them. This principle of "having in mind" can be extended to habit (don't know the source for this nor do I know it's particulars). Does the above scenario of the coffee fall into the habit/having-in-mind principle?

Comment: I think you really need to expand this question with some of your underlying assumptions and what principles you think might apply. We're not here to Pasken, so don't assume we're all perfectly well versed in the minutiae of Hilchos Coffee. Don't approach this site like you would your rabbi. What's driving you to ask this question? What are you confused about? What's your (no irony intended) [tag:kavana-intent]

Comment: SethJ, Are you personally unaware of the assumptions I am making or are you referring to future readers of the question?

Comment: If I spell out all the halachos/assumptions I wouldn't need to ask the question...

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18662/759

Comment: @ani To me, this question came off ([until 29 minutes ago](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/53246/revisions)) like you were asking if you're allowed to do something that you suspect you're not allowed to do, if, given certain specific circumstances, the prohibition (or maybe 'rule' is a better word here) you're trying to avoid may not apply. This would have been very 'Psak-y' if you ask me, and it just sounded like a question for your rabbi. Broken down to its parts, it's not only more easily answerable, but it's much more educational and less personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/18_devarim.html). This is a partial answer.

> **Within one’s house, we have an assumption that when he makes a bracha he subconsciously intends to exempt any other food of that same
>   beracha**. Therefore, if one makes a shehakol on orange juice, he can
>   also eat other shehakol foods without making a new bracha.
>   Additionally, when one makes hamotzei in his house, we assume his
>   bracha covers all meal-like foods in his home. Unless one normally
>   receives gifts of food from neighbors or friends during the day, such
>   gifts that arrive during one’s meal would require their own bracha
>   (even if it’s chicken).

SInce it states, "within one's house", moving to another room does not require to say a new bracha on the coffee. There is a separate problem, though that is unclear from your question. Are you having the coffee as part of your meal or afterwards?

I believe that if you make a bracha acharona on the chicken, that ends the meal. Also, I think that after 72 minutes, you need to makea new bracha as well. I am quite certain that there are other M.Y. questions that address these 2 areas, but I have to research these, later.

Comment: Don't shehakol brachos expire after 30 minutes?

Comment: @AniYodea source for this? B'rachas remain active as long as there is no hefsek.

Comment: Cash cow or until you start feeling hungry again.